# The CIDR is invalid AWS Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, cidr

I am using cloud formation to create instances, I am using following CIDR configurations for VPC and subnets.

```
VPC CIDR: "10.15.0.0/16" 
Subnet A CIDR: "10.15.10.0/24"
Subnet B CIDR: "10.15.20.0/24"
PrivateSubnet CIDR A: "10.15.90.0/21"
PrivateSubnet CIDR B: "10.15.110.0/21"
```

I am getting following error. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here ?

```
The CIDR '10.15.20.0/24' is invalid. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidSubnet.Range; )
```

Comment: Why is there a stray dot inside `"10.15.0.0./16"`?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, It was a typo. I have corrected this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`10.15.20.0/24` is fine.

However, `10.15.90.0/21` and `10.15.110.0/21` are **invalid**.

- `10.15.90.0/21` falls within **`10.15.88.0`** to `10.15.95.255`, so it should really be `10.15.88.0/21`
- `10.15.110.0/21` falls within **`10.15.104.0`** to `10.15.111.255`, so it should really be `10.15.104.0/21`

CIDR notation hurts the head, so you always use a [CIDR Calculator](https://www.google.com/search?q=cidr+calculator).

If you don't follow the above concepts, read [Classless Inter-Domain Routing - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).